# Using SSJS can you set a response status code?

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, httprequest, ssjs

In cloudpages, I've been trying to build a handler page for an ajax form POST that checks a certain DE to prevent duplicate submissions. It needs to return "duplicate entry, not saved" or "successfully saved" etc

I am aware that SSJS can set response headers, but it doesn't look like it can set status codes. Thus every request comes back with status: 200 even if the body of the response contains error information.

I have tried using a JSON code resource type, but I can't get SSJS to modify anything "lower level" than response headers.

How exactly can I return a "form post fail: duplicate entry exists" status code to my Jquery ajax form submit page?

Comment: Why not just parse the result in your handler page and return the appropriate string to the calling page?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure that this would work, but you could try the SSJS [RaiseError](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformUtilityRaiseError.htm) function, here's an example:

```
<script runat="server">     
 var StatusAndRequestID = [0,0];
 var newObject = Platform.Function.InvokeCreate(CreateRequest,StatusAndRequestID,Options);
 var status = StatusAndRequestID[0];
 var requestID = StatusAndRequestID[1];     if(Result != "OK") {
 Platform.Function.RaiseError("Create failed. Ensure your call successfully invoked the Create method.",false,"statusCode","3");
     }
</script>
```